# AttributeError in my Python code

Tags: python-2.7, attributes

I am fairly new in python.
I am parsing a big file and I want to check that the different inputs are correct, especially if the ID entered is in the file header.
When I run the following code, I get this error message:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'

---

```
filename = str(raw_input('enter filename: '))

try:
    with open(filename, 'rU'): pass
except IOError:
    print 'The file does not exist'
    sys.exit(0)

def findID(w):
    return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search

while True:
    ID = (raw_input("Enter ID: ")).upper()
    IDheader = ID + ".NA"
    with open(filename, 'rU') as f: 
        first_line = f.readline()
    if findID(IDheader)(first_line):
        print "you entered ",ID
        break
    else:
        pass
        print "ID not in this file."`


for line in filename.readlines():
    Line = line.split() 

    if...
```

---

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filename` is a filename, not a file handle. You need to open it:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        line = line.split()
```